# Invalid Property: expected Array, but got undefined

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vue-component

I have a Vue component Shoes, which uses component Products, WHICH USES component Product. I am getting an array using API for component Products, which fills component Product with information.

When I'm trying to get an array from API in Shoes component, all goes successfully, and when I'm trying to give an array to Products component (which requires Array), Vue says that got Undefined. What the...

"Shoes" component:

```html
<!-- eslint-disable-next-line -->

<template>
  <div>
    <app-products :new_products="new_products" :old_products="old_products"></app-products>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
    import getData from "../data/get_data";
    // importing API function
    export default {
        data() {
            return {

            }
        },
        methods: {
            async getShoes () {

                const response = await getData('products', 'shoes');

                const new_products = [],
                    old_products = [];

                for (const product of response.data)
                    product.tag === 'new' ? new_products.push(product) : old_products.push(product);

                console.log(this.products.new, this.products.old);

                this.new_products = new_products;
                this.old_products = old_products;

                console.log(this.products.new, this.products.old);
            }
        },
        async mounted() {
            await this.getShoes()
        }
    }

</script>

<style>

</style>
```

---

Products component:

```html
<template>
   <div>
     <div class="wrap wrap_for_new" v-if="new_products.length !== 0">
       <h1 class="write" >Эти товары поступили <b class="red">недавно!</b></h1>
       <div class="main_wrap">
         <app-product v-for="(product, key) of new_products"  class="new_product" :key="key" :name="product.name" :descriptions="product.description" :price="product.price" :ImageId="product.id" :count="product.count"></app-product>
       </div>
     </div>
     <div class="wrap" v-if="old_products.length !== 0">
       <div class="main_wrap">
         <app-product v-for="(product, key) of old_products" :key="key" :name="product.name" :descriptions="product.description" :price="product.price" :ImageId="product.id" :count="product.count"></app-product>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: {
            new_products: {
                type: Array,
                required: true
            },
            old_products: {
                type: Array,
                required: true
            }
        },
        methods: {
            setGridColumns() {
                let ret_ = '';

                for (let i = 0; i < Math.round(window.innerWidth / 170); i++) {
                    ret_ += '1fr ';
                }

                for (let el of document.querySelectorAll('.main_wrap')) el.style.gridTemplateColumns = ret_;
            },
        },
        async beforeCreate() {

            console.log(this.new_products, this.old_products);

            this.setGridColumns();
        }
    }
</script>

<style>

  .wrap_for_new {
    margin-top: 50px;
  }

  .wrap {
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  }

.main_wrap {
  position: relative;
  display: grid;
  height: 100%;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-gap: 5px;
}

  .new_product {
    border: red solid 1px !important;
  }

  .write {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 150%;
  }

  .red {
    color: red;
  }

  .write span {
    color: red;
  }
</style>
```

---

Product component:

```html
<template>
<!--  :class=" classObject "-->
    <div class="product" >
<!--      {{ name }} - {{ descriptions }} - {{ price }} - {{ ImageId }}-->

      <div class="look" @click="look">
        Просмотреть
      </div>

      <img :src="`localhost:8000/image/${ImageId}`" class="image_still"  :alt="`${name} product image`"/>

      <div class="product_name"> {{ name }} </div>

      <div class="descriptions">{{descriptions | toolongtext}}</div>

      <div class="price"> {{price}} </div>

      <div class="count"> {{count}} items </div>

    </div>

</template>
<script>
    import { animate } from '../staticFunctions/animate';
    import emitter from "../../src/main";

    export default {
        props: {
            name: String,
            descriptions: String,
            price: String,
            ImageId: String,
            count: Number
        },
        methods: {
          look() {
              emitter.$emit('look', {
                  name: this.name,
                  descriptions: this.descriptions,
                  price: this.price,
                  ImageId: this.ImageId,
                  count: this.count
              });
              animate('product-look', false);
              this.isOpened = !this.isOpened;
          }
        },
        filters: {
            toolongtext: value => value.length > 51 ? value.slice(0, 51) + '...' : value
        }
    }
</script>

<style scoped>
  .product {
      height: 400px;
    width: 90%;
    background-color: #fafafa;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px gray;
    margin: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    float: left;
    max-width: 90vw;
    max-height: 90vw;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 0.5fr 4fr 1fr 2fr 1fr;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-areas:
      "look look"
      "img img"
      "name name"
      "desc desc"
      "prc count";
  }
  .look {
    opacity: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    grid-area: look;
    transition: opacity 1s;
  }

  .product:hover .look,
  .product:active .look {
    opacity: 0.6;
  }

  .product * {
    text-align: center;
  }

  .descriptions {
    grid-area: desc;
  }

  .image_still {
    grid-area: img;
  }

  .product_name {
    grid-area: name;
  }

  .price {
    grid-area: prc;
  }

  .count {
    grid-area: count;
  }



</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never define `new_products` or `old_products` under `data` in your `Shoes` component:

```
data() {
    return {

    }
},
```

Instead, you just assign to them:

```
this.new_products = new_products;
this.old_products = old_products;
```

But they're not reactive, so they're `undefined`. Define them:

```
data() {
    return {
        new_products: [],
        old_products: []
    }
},
```

Also, you must follow the properties naming convention, either `lowerCamcelCase` or `kebab-case`, but never `snake_case`.

For example:

```
:new-products="new_products"
```

Instead of:

```
:new_products="new_products"
```